# Microsoft Project: Prevent popup to save file when closing

Tags: vb6, ms-office, office-interop, ms-project

I'm performing some Office Automation with Microsoft Project 2016. If I open a 2016 mpp file there's no issue, I can close the application. However, if I open a 2003 or 2007 file on MS Project 2016, I always get a popup when closing the app asking me to upgrade the file to the newer version.

As there's no way no interact with this dialogs in automation, it is completely blocking the process and breaking the app.

Is there any registry key or configuration that can be done in Office or MS Project to disable this file upgrade popup when closing?

```
Dim objMPP As New MSProject.Application

objMPP.Visible = True
objMPP.DisplayAlerts = False
objMPP.ShowWelcome = False

If Not objMPP.FileOpenEx(strFile, True, NoAuto:=True, openpool:=pjPoolReadOnly, ignorereadonlyrecommended:=True) Then
    Exit Function
End If

... some more code code here

objMPP.FileCloseAllEx

Set objMPP = Nothing
```

Comment: Does it turn the prompt off if you add `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` before you exit

Comment: @dbmitch Well that line is right at the beginning of the automation, would it make a difference to repeat it at the end?

Comment: If you have code then please share it. Saves a lot of guesswork answers

Comment: Are you editing the file and saving it at the end when you exit?

Comment: @dbmitch I will add some code in a bit in case it helps. I'm not saving the file in the automation. Open it, read a few things that I need and close it out. In fact, if I open the file myself on MSProject and close it immediately the app asks me if I want to save it in the new version. I think there should be a way to disable this behavior.

Comment: Sure - edit our question and add the code at the bottom - don't add in a comment. You should see what happens if you open it as Readonly - second argument of  `app.FileOpenEx(msprojectefilename, True)` - and on the exit use  `app.FileClose pjDoNotSave` for not saving before closing

Comment: @dbmitch I added a code snippet on the question. As you can see there the file is being opened with the read-only flag as true.

Comment: What if you specify the specify `FormatID` parameter like `"MSProject.mpp.12"` for version 2012 or `"MSProject.mpp.9"` for version 2003? Even if it is Readonly can you specifying not saving by `objMPP.FileCloseAllEx pjDoNotSave` to see if that works?

Comment: @dbmitch I tried pjDoNotSave (and Zero) before and it didn't make any difference. It still doesn't close. Where should I specify the FormatID?

Comment: It's the 10th parameter, but if you specify it at the end like `,FormatID:=""` I don;'t think you need to include all the other optional empty fields and commas  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/application-fileopenex-method-project

Comment: @dbmitch Ohh I see, but as I can receive any of the 3 file types, I don't see how could I make it dynamic before opening the file. **Thank you so much for your help up to this point sir! :)** Any other suggestion is more than welcome